# Reusable component outside of components/schema?

Tags: swagger, openapi

Is there another place to put reusable components outside of `components/schema`?

I have a "partial" (for lack of a better term) that I'd like to `$ref` elsewhere, but I do not want as a "Model":

Some examples:

```
NotFoundError:
  type: object
  properties:
    code:
      type: integer
      format: int32
      example: 404
    message:
      type: string
      example: "Resource Not Found"
ID-Array:
  type: array
  items:
    $ref: '#/components/schemas/ID'
  writeOnly: true
ID:
  type: integer
  format: int32
  example: 1
ID-ReadOnly:
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/ID'
    - readOnly: true
ID-WriteOnly:
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/ID'
    - writeOnly: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to put the partials under some [extension key](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.1.md#specificationExtensions), say `x-partials`, and change the `$ref`s accordingly. `$ref` does not care what the path is as long as the target is in the expected format.

```yaml
x-partials:
  ID:
    type: integer
    format: int32
    example: 1

components:
  schemas:
    ID-Array:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: '#/x-partials/ID'
      writeOnly: true
    ID-ReadOnly:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/x-partials/ID'
        - readOnly: true
    ID-WriteOnly:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/x-partials/ID'
        - writeOnly: true
```

This way, for example, the partials won't show up in the "Models" section of Swagger UI.